# Unabel to create subfolder in python

Tags: python-3.x, subdirectory

I am trying to create a folder(exports) and a subfolder(file_name) using the below code. 
Every time I run this code, I get an error:

> [WinError 3]The system cannot find the path specified: C:/temp/postgre_exports/filename.

`dim_file` table contains the file details.

`df.iat[0,5]` will give the actual file_name that I want to pass to variable `mypath`

```
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM qwerty.dim_file", conn)

file_name=df.iat[0,5]

mypath="C:/temp/exports/%s"%file_name

if not os.path.exists(mypath):
    os.makedirs(mypath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the backward slash in representing file hierarchies unlike unix based systems. So, you should replace the relevant line of code with the following.

```py
mypath = "C:\temp\exports\%s"%file_name
```

But as a best practise, you should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) which joins paths intelligently. Then the code would be as follows.

```py
mypath = os.path.join('c:','/','temp', 'exports', file_name)
```

Comment: and for even better practise, use `os.sep` to determine the seperator that needs to be used, instead of hardcoding `'/'`. Because with this code, `os.path.join` will not convert the forward slash into a backslash for you automatically, so the path would still fail.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Still the error message does not go away. I am able to get the desired path printed on console. But the folder does not get created.